# Как получить url аватарки пользователя? VkNet

Tags: c#, vknet

Мне нужно загрузить в picturebox аватарку пользователя по id. Для этого мне нужно получить url аватарки. Метод `User.PhotoId` возвращает id аватарки, как мне из этого id получить url?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/users.get и https://vk.com/dev/objects/user_2

Comment: И что мне с этим делать? Сейчас вам объясню поподробней. Я использовал метод Users.Get, и имею поле PhotoId. Оно возвращает id аватарки. А мне нужен url этой картинки, которая на аватарке.

Comment: Я могу вам код свой дать, если он вам нужен.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий: ну так и возьмите нужное Вам поле, а не ID аватарки

Comment: @Арсений Кривецкий, вот здесь написано vk.com/dev/objects/user_2  чтобы получить url нужно в запросе отправить photo_50 или там еще есть, получишь url картинки.

Comment: @Арсений Кривецкий, И здесь в конце есть пример запроса vk.com/dev/users.get

Comment: @Sergey_73, точно, спасибо вам большое!